# SvcHost using too much RAM

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, memory, service

I have a problem. A specific instance of SvcHost is using way too much ram (680MB). I've found that the following services are running under this process:

[image: SvcHost Process]

I've stopped and then started all services I was able to but the memory usage only dropped to 580MB. Here's what I found:

- **Certificate Propagation** - could not stop, freed 50MB while trying.
- **Group Policy Client** - could not stop.
- **Task Scheduler** - could not stop, freed 30MB while trying.
- **System Event Notification Service** - could not stop.
- **Remote Desktop Service** - didnot stop since I am remoted in.
- **Windows Management Instrumentation** - freed 30MB.
- **Windows Update** - freed 60MB.

Which of the

Answer (score 1):

For me, the culprit turned out to be the [Certificate Propagation Service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff404288%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). Sounds like it's used to install certificates from smart cards. Well, this is a VM so I disabled that sucker!